# How to remove symbols from list elements in python

Tags: python

I have a list that has various things in it and looks similar to this:

```
exList = ['JM = {12, 23, 34, 45, 56}', 'the quick brown fox', 'word ($(,))']
```

I am currently iterating through it like this:

```
def myFunction(exList)
  result = []
  yElement = exList[0]

  for ch in yElement:
    if ch in SYMBOLS:    #I have a list of symbols saved globally in another area
      exList.remove(ch)
  result = exList
```

I have tried several other ways of solving this but am getting nowhere.  My question is how can I iterate through the list elements and remove all the symbols, and then go on to the next list element?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SYMBOLS = '{}()[].,:;+-*/&|<>=~'
```

and I would like to end up with a list like:

```
['JM', 'the quick brown fox', 'word']
```

Comment: Post `SYMBOLS` list as well as expected output.

Comment: SYMBOLS = '{}()[].,:;+-*/&|<>=~' and I would like to end up with a list like: ['JM', 'the quick brown fox', 'word']

Comment: That doesn't look like a list.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary SYMBOLS doesn't look like a list and it doesn't match the expected output, digits are not in the list of symbols but they are removed from output. From the output it seems that SymbolsToBeRemoved should be a string: '0123456789!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'. Is that right?

Comment: @user2722670 What would be the expected output for: `"JM = ['foo', 'bar']"`?

Comment: That's correct.  I wasn't very accurate with my question and should have included all the details.  I was really looking for a way to just iterate through the list items and remove what I didn't want and I appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> SYMBOLS = '{}()[].,:;+-*/&|<>=~$1234567890'
>>> strings = ['JM = {12, 23, 34, 45, 56}', 'the quick brown fox', 'word ($(,))']
>>> [item.translate(None, SYMBOLS).strip() for item in strings]
['JM', 'the quick brown fox', 'word']
```

You have to add the numbers as well to the `SYMBOLS` if you want the first string to look like `JM`, and you're missing also the `$` character.

From the documentation:

> S.translate(table [,deletechars]) -> string
>
> Return a copy of the string S, where all characters occurring in the optional argument deletechars are removed, and the remaining characters have been mapped through the given translation table, which must be a string of length 256 or None. If the table argument is None, no translation is applied and the operation simply removes the characters in deletechars.

You can do it with regular expressions too, but this is much cleaner this way if you only need a simple replace.

Answer (score 2):

```
exList = ['JM = {12, 23, 34, 45, 56}', 'the quick brown fox', 'word ($(,))']
SYMBOLS = '{}()[].,:;+-*/&|<>=~' 

results = []
for element in exList:
    temp = ""
    for ch in element:
        if ch not in SYMBOLS:
            temp += ch

    results.append(temp)

print results
```

Answer (score 1):

An extension of the code you posted initially:

```
SYMBOLS = '${}()[].,:;+-*/&|<>=~1234567890'
def myFunction(exList):
    result = map(lambda Element: Element.translate(None, SYMBOLS).strip(), exList)  
    return result

exList = ['JM = {12, 23, 34, 45, 56}', 'the quick brown fox', 'word ($(,))']
print myFunction(exList)
```

Output:

```
['JM', 'the quick brown fox', 'word']
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using string.translate method and passing it a list of punctuation signs? This may be the easiest method.

```
>>> exList = ['JM = {12, 23, 34, 45, 56}', 'the quick brown fox', 'word ($(,))']
>>> import string
>>> cleanList = []
>>> string.punctuation
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
>>> for i in exList:
    cleanList.append(i.translate(None,string.punctuation+string.digits))
>>> cleanList
['JM', 'the quick brown fox', 'word ']
>>>
```

String translate may be used to remove the chars from a string, it is used like so:

```
>>> k = "{}()hello$"
>>> k.translate(None,string.punctuation)
'hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
SYMBOLS = '{}()[].,:;+-*/&|<>=~$1234567890'
strings = ['JM = {12, 23, 34, 45, 56}', 'the quick brown fox', 'word ($(,))']
[item.translate({ord(SYM): None for SYM in SYMBOLS} ).strip() for item in strings]
```

Comment: Pleas add some explanation to your code. The question is very old and already has many answers - maybe add why your answer is unique and important to be kept. Thanks